# Making a json structure with nested serializers concept

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an api with Django Rest Framework , the api format looks like this, I'm new to nested serializer concept so I've tried to make relational models and nested serializer that is available in the documentation but it doesn't work for me , is there anyone who can help ?

```
{
    "devices": {
        "device": [{
            "type": "MP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:10",
            "MP_name": "MP1",
            "SN": "EMSMP001",
            "plant_name": "Greenaftech",
            "gatway_name": "gw1",
            "adress": 1,
            "baud_rate": 9600,
            "voltage": 230,
            "current": 10,
            "active_power": 2.3,
            "reactive_power": 0.01,
            "apparent_power": 2.3,
            "FP": 0.99,
            "frequency": 49.98
        },
        {
            "type": "TP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:10",
            "TP_name": "TP1",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"Greenaftech",
            "gatway_name":"gw1",
            "adress": 12,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "UA":1,
            "UB":1,
            "UC":1,
            "UAB":1,
            "UBC":1,
            "UAC":1,
            "IA":1,
            "IB":20,
            "IC":43,
            "frequency":11,
            "Pa":88,
            "Pb":30,
            "Pc":23,
            "Pt":42,
            "Qa":21,
            "Qb":31,
            "Qc":49,
            "Qt":82,
            "Sa":63,
            "Sb":83,
            "Sc":10,
            "St":39,
            "FPa":54,
            "FPb":43,
            "FPc":34,
            "FPt":87,
            "THDV":56,
            "THDI":74,
            "max_demand":2,
            "count_E":8,
            "count_Er":55
        },
        {
            "type": "VFD",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:10",
            "vfd_name": "VFD1",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"plant1",
            "gatway_name":"gw3",
            "adress": 7,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "c00":8,
            "c01":8,
            "c02":8,
            "c03":8,
            "c04":8,
            "c06":8,
            "c07":8,
            "c12":8,
            "c13":8,
            "c14":8,
            "c15":8,
            "c16":8,
            "c17":8,
            "c18":8,
            "c19":8,
            "c20":8,
            "c21":8,
            "c23":8,
            "c24":8,
            "c25":8,
            "c27":8
        },
        {
            "type": "MP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "MP_name": "MP2",
            "SN": "EMSMP001",
            "plant_name": "plant1",
            "gatway_name": "gw3",
            "adress": 1,
            "baud_rate": 9600,
            "voltage": 230,
            "current": 10,
            "active_power": 2.3,
            "reactive_power": 0.01,
            "apparent_power": 2.3,
            "FP": 0.99,
            "frequency": 49.98
        },
        {
            "type": "TP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "TP_name": "TP2",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"plant1",
            "gatway_name":"gw11",
            "adress": 1,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "UA":1,
            "UB":1,
            "UC":1,
            "UAB":1,
            "UBC":1,
            "UAC":1,
            "IA":1,
            "IB":20,
            "IC":43,
            "frequency":11,
            "Pa":88,
            "Pb":30,
            "Pc":23,
            "Pt":42,
            "Qa":21,
            "Qb":31,
            "Qc":49,
            "Qt":82,
            "Sa":63,
            "Sb":83,
            "Sc":10,
            "St":39,
            "FPa":54,
            "FPb":43,
            "FPc":34,
            "FPt":87,
            "THDV":56,
            "THDI":74,
            "max_demand":2,
            "count_E":8,
            "count_Er":55
        },
        {
            "type": "VFD",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "vfd_name": "VFD2",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"Greenaftech",
            "gatway_name":"gw1",
            "adress": 7,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "c00":8,
            "c01":36,
            "c02":44,
            "c03":15,
            "c04":28,
            "c06":41,
            "c07":56,
            "c12":10,
            "c13":11,
            "c14":7,
            "c15":893,
            "c16":12,
            "c17":60,
            "c18":46,
            "c19":83,
            "c20":47,
            "c21":83,
            "c23":20,
            "c24":32,
            "c25":89,
            "c27":58
        },
        {
            "type": "MP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "MP_name": "MP3",
            "SN": "EMSMP001",
            "plant_name": "ilisi",
            "gatway_name": "gw2",
            "adress": 1,
            "baud_rate": 9600,
            "voltage": 230,
            "current": 10,
            "active_power": 2.3,
            "reactive_power": 0.01,
            "apparent_power": 2.3,
            "FP": 0.99,
            "frequency": 49.98
        },
        {
            "type": "TP",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "TP_name": "TR2",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"ilisi",
            "gatway_name":"gw2",
            "adress": 1,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "UA":1,
            "UB":1,
            "UC":1,
            "UAB":1,
            "UBC":1,
            "UAC":1,
            "IA":1,
            "IB":20,
            "IC":43,
            "frequency":11,
            "Pa":88,
            "Pb":30,
            "Pc":23,
            "Pt":42,
            "Qa":21,
            "Qb":31,
            "Qc":49,
            "Qt":82,
            "Sa":63,
            "Sb":83,
            "Sc":10,
            "St":39,
            "FPa":54,
            "FPb":43,
            "FPc":34,
            "FPt":87,
            "THDV":56,
            "THDI":74,
            "max_demand":2,
            "count_E":8,
            "count_Er":55
        },
        {
            "type": "VFD",
            "time": "18/05/2022, 15:15:15",
            "vfd_name": "VFD3",
            "SN": "EMSMP002",
            "plant_name":"plant1",
            "gatway_name":"gw3",
            "adress": 7,
            "baud_rate":1,
            "c00":8,
            "c01":8,
            "c02":8,
            "c03":8,
            "c04":8,
            "c06":8,
            "c07":8,
            "c12":8,
            "c13":8,
            "c14":8,
            "c15":8,
            "c16":8,
            "c17":8,
            "c18":8,
            "c19":8,
            "c20":8,
            "c21":8,
            "c23":8,
            "c24":8,
            "c25":8,
            "c27":8
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

**this is my models.py**

```
class MP(models.Model):
    Monophase_Type=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=infos_VFD)
    Monophase_Time= models.DateTimeField()
    
    MonoPhase_Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Serial_Number=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Plant_Name=models.ManyToManyField(Plant)
    Gateway_Name=models.ManyToManyField(Gateway)
    Adress=models.IntegerField()
    baud_rate=models.FloatField()
    Voltage=models.FloatField() 
    Current=models.FloatField()
    Active_Power= models.FloatField()
    Apparent_Power=models.FloatField()
    FP=models.FloatField()
    frenquency=models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return MonoPhase_Name
    
class TP(models.Model):
    Triphase_Type=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=infos_VFD)
    Triphase_Time= models.DateTimeField()
    Triphase_Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Serial_Number=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Plant_Name=models.ManyToManyField(Plant)
    Gateway_Name=models.ManyToManyField(Gateway)
    Adress=models.IntegerField()
    Baud_Rate=models.FloatField()
    UA=models.FloatField()
    UB=models.FloatField()
    UC=models.FloatField()
    UAB=models.FloatField()
    UBC=models.FloatField()
    UAC=models.FloatField()
    IA=models.FloatField()
    IB=models.FloatField()
    IC=models.FloatField()
    frequency=models.FloatField()
    Pa=models.FloatField()
    Pb=models.FloatField()
    Pc=models.FloatField()
    Pt=models.FloatField()
    Qa=models.FloatField()
    Qb=models.FloatField()
    Qc=models.FloatField()
    Qt=models.FloatField()
    Sa=models.FloatField()
    Sb=models.FloatField()
    Sc=models.FloatField()
    St=models.FloatField()
    FPa=models.FloatField()
    FPb=models.FloatField()
    FPc=models.FloatField()
    FPt=models.FloatField()
    THDV=models.FloatField()
    THDI=models.FloatField()
    max_demand=models.FloatField()
    count_E=models.FloatField()
    count_Er=models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return Triphase_Name   


class api(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    

class vfdd(models.Model):
    VFDd_Typee=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=infos_VFD)
    VFDd_Timee= models.DateTimeField()
    VFDd_Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Serial_Number1=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Plant_Namee=models.ManyToManyField(Plant)
    Gateway_Namee=models.ManyToManyField(Gateway)
    Adresss=models.IntegerField()
    baud_ratee=models.FloatField()
    c00=models.FloatField()
    c01=models.FloatField()
    c02=models.FloatField()
    c03=models.FloatField()
    c04=models.FloatField()
    c06=models.FloatField()
    c07=models.FloatField()
    c12=models.FloatField()
    c13=models.FloatField()
    c14=models.FloatField()
    c15=models.FloatField()
    c16=models.FloatField()
    c17=models.FloatField()
    c18=models.FloatField()
    c19=models.FloatField()
    c20=models.FloatField()
    c21=models.FloatField()
    c23=models.FloatField()
    c24=models.FloatField()
    c25=models.FloatField()
    c27=models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.VFDd_Name
```

**this is my serializers.py  :**

```
class MPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
class TPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
        
class VFDDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vfdd
        fields = '__all__'    
        
        
class apiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device1=MPSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    device2=TPSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    device3=VFDDSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)                               
    class Meta:
        model = api
        fields = '__all__'
```

**and these are my views :**

```
class apiListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class= apiSerializer
    queryset= api.objects.all()
    
    
class deviceListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class= MPSerializer
    queryset= MP.objects.all()
```

Comment: The api model doesn’t have any reference to other models. How its gonna know which device to pass?

Comment: i added a new param , const=models.ForeignKey(api,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='d2') 
for the 3 devices that  I have , that make it a relation , but still no use

Comment: I get it , I have to pass the "related_names" to my variables in API serializer , thanks man

Answer (score 0):

So you can so something like this .

This is your serializers

```
class MPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "MP"

    class Meta:
        model = MP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
class TPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "TP"
    class Meta:
        model = TP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
        
class VFDDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "VFDD"

    class Meta:
        model = vfdd
        fields = '__all__'
```

and you can create a view like this

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from . import real_time_serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response

Class deviceList(APIView):
   permission_classes = [] # if you have any permission classes.
  
   def get (self, request):
      mp = MpModel.objects.all()
      tp = TpModel.objects.all()
      vfdd = VfddModel.objects.all()

      mp_data = real_time_serializers.MPSerializer(mp, many=True).data
      tp_data = real_time_serializers.TPSerializer(tp, many=True).data
      vffdd_data = real_time_serializers. VFDDSerializer(vfdd, many=True).data

      nested_data = mp_data.extend(tp_data + vffdd_data)
      
      res = {
           "devices": nested_data
          }
      return Response(res)
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

You can create a new view for the "PUT" &  DELETE methods.

SO your urls can be like this.

```
path("some_name/<int:id>/<type>/", views.UpdateDeleteView..as_view())
```

and function can be like this.

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Class UpdateDeleteView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
   permission_classes = [] # if you have any permission classes.
   lookup_field = "id"
   
   def get_queryset(self):
      if self.kwargs["type"] = "mp":
         return MpModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id']) 
      elif self.kwargs["type"] = "tp":
         return TpModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id'])
      elif self.kwargs["type"] = "vffdd_data":
         return VfddModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

Comment: thank u , how can I implement  PUT & DELETE methods ?

Comment: I have updated answer @ShacoPoggers you can do something like this

Comment: ok I'm trying to figure out about this error module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'MPSerializer'

Comment: do u have any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: Delete method is working , but when I'm trying the PUT method it returns an empty string , here is the data : https://ibb.co/7p4NR4P
https://ibb.co/wW1QBKS

Answer (score 0):

this is my views.py :

```
from . import serializers              
class deviceList(APIView):
   permission_classes = [] # if you have any permission classes.
  
   def get (self, request):
      mp = MP.objects.all()
      tp = TP.objects.all()
      vfd = vfddModel.objects.all()

      mp_data = serializers.MPSerializer(mp, many=True).data
      tp_data = serializers.TPSerializer(tp, many=True).data
      vffdd_data = serializers. VFDDSerializer(vfd, many=True).data

      nested_data = mp_data.extend(tp_data + vffdd_data)
      
      res = {
           "devices": nested_data
          }
      return Response(res)
```

this is my serializer.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .real_time_models import *           
class MPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "MP"

    class Meta:
        model = MP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
class TPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "TP"
    class Meta:
        model = TP 
        fields = '__all__'
        
        
class VFDDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return "VFDD"

    class Meta:
        model = vfdd
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: @Rahul Raj , the error that i get is  'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'MPSerializer'

Comment: Your "serializer" and "views" are in the same folder, and you have "serializer.py" and you imported "from. import serializers"   you should import like this " from. import serializer" if both files exists in the same folder.

Comment: https://ibb.co/3BqHR8q this is my folder , I didn't understnad what should I do ?

Comment: "from . import real_time_serializers" because your "real_time_serializers" this name of your file.

Comment: I've tried this but no use : from authapp.real_time_monitoring.real_time_serializers import serializers

Comment: thanks it worked , https://ibb.co/zNfz7ZX , is it supposed to show up like this ? cuz I need to implement POST method also

Comment: its just GET method to show only data

Comment: can you create POST method for me please ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).